# Values for volume, area and length in Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, dataformat

I'm using *Forge* to extract data from *Revit* models (transformed to *.nwc*). I call

> GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties

to get all properties of my model. The problem is that for some reason values for volume, area and length for all Revit objects are now in the format *"0.009 ft^3"*, while before they all were just numbers. What can be the reason for this? Is this an API change or the model is saved with some special parameters, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a change because previously you could not tell the unit of any of the values. Now it's showing the values as you find them in the Viewer as well.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Any support for meters?

Comment: You mean if there is a way to get those values in meter instead? Then, no. The values will always be in what the original file stored them in. So you would have to convert them yourself.